# iPhone OpenGL ES missing functions should be there - glBlendFuncSeparate etc

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, opengl-es

I'm using OpenGL ES 1.1 on the iPhone, and I'd like to use the following functions:

```
glBlendFuncSeparate
glBlendColor
```

With their related constants. These didn't exist in early iPhone GL implementations, but according to this page:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/releasenotes/General/iPhone30APIDiffs/index.html

they should be there in 3.0+, which I'm building for. But I'm getting "implicit definition" warnings. What do I need to do to get those functions?

Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm. After spelunking in the headers, it seems as if this function might be defined only for ES v2, not for ES v1.1 which is what my project uses. Anyone have any knowledge about this? I think the lib is the same; is it possible to hijack these functions from ES2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These functions are only defined for OpenGL ES 2.0. `glBlendFuncSeparate` does have a 1.1 extension version as `glBlendFuncSeparateOES`, but there is no equivalent for `glBlendColor`.

Answer (score 0):

Extensions are included in the `glext.h` header files.  Specifically, `#include <OpenGLES/ES1/glext.h>`

Comment: As an extension in ES1, the functions and enums have an OES suffix (http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_blend_func_separate.txt).

Comment: Looks like glBlendFuncSeparate is present as glBlendFuncSeparateOES. glBlendColor does not appear to have an equivalent in openGL ES 1.1.