# glBlendFuncSeparate crashes on OpenGL1.1 on iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, alphablending

I'm trying to build code on an older iOS devices that have arm6 processors and support for only OpenGL ES 1.1. The function glBlendFuncSeparate crashes. I found this post on stackoverflow -

[iPhone OpenGL ES missing functions should be there - glBlendFuncSeparate etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814881/iphone-opengl-es-missing-functions-should-be-there-glblendfuncseparate-etc?s=e9d4d004-d144-459c-95e6-a1b95d161d13)

So I added the OES to the end of the function and it still crashes. I've double checked to make sure I am including OpenGLES/ES1/glext.h and I am.

Does anyone know what the deal is with this? Is this function supported in OpenGLES 1.1 on iOS? If so, how do you use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much research and work, I've found that glBlendFuncSeparate is not supported on OpenGLES 1.1 for iOS on older devices.

The easiest work around we found (though is does involve more draw calls) is to use glColorMask. You mask off the alpha and set your blend mode and draw once, then you mask off you color and set your alpha blend mode and draw again.

Hope this helps others with the same problem!